# Get active module: Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am currently implementing a feature in Angular 7 application where, in the header, I need to highlight the name of the module that is active. For example, we have 3 modules:

1. Shopping cart
2. My Orders
3. Inventory

Depending on the active module (any page of that module can be active), I need to highlight one of these options. Using the following, I can get the active route:

```
this.router.url
```

But, how can I see what modules are currently active?

Comment: did you try `routerLinkActive`

Comment: @Aravind I think routerLinkActive is only useful for matching the exact route, and not the module itself. I was thinking more about ActivatedRoute, but not sure if that info is available in ActivatedRoute.

Comment: Seems like this isn't possible. You probably have to use the data field in the route.